# Как автоматически поставить infer constraints

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В моей версии приложения нет так расположен функционал, не могу найти, помогите, я новичок

[image: Это видео обучения]

[image: Это мой экран]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например в вкладке design там где вы находитесь есть такая кнопка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]